# Tensorflow: Feeding large datasets of JPEGs to frozen inference graphs

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a frozen graph in tensorflow that is set up to take (batchsize, 224,224, 3) as input. Thus not taking an input function. I want to change it to take 50000 real images from a data folder. How do I feed those images into the metagraph without going over the memory limit? 
I know that I could feed it as an input function but that would mean changing my frozen graph. Any suggestions of avoiding that?
Is the only way to convert the input to take in a function. I would like not to modify the frozen graphs.
This is the code I use to load my graph:

```
dummy_input = np.random.random_sample((batch_size,224,224,3))
tf.reset_default_graph()
g = tf.Graph()
outlist=[]
with g.as_default():
    #processing the data
    inc=tf.constant(dummy_input, dtype=tf.float32)
    dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(inc)
    dataset=dataset.repeat()
    iterator=dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    next_element=iterator.get_next()
    # loading the graph
    out = tf.import_graph_def(
      graph_def=gdef,
      input_map={input_layer:next_element}, # input layer name of the model is required fro this
      return_elements=[output_layer] # here is output layer name.
    )
    out = out[0].outputs[0]
    outlist.append(out)
```